# React "'List' cannot be used as a JSX Element" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript

I'm doing component's nodejs version upgrade in reactjs and I have component named 'FilterBar'. While this component works on nodejs 8, it cannot be built after upgrading to nodejs version 13 and starting to use TypeScript. The error given during build is as follows:

filterbar.tsx (Error lines are shown with arrows):

```
  renderResultList = (resultList): JSX.Element => {
    let listProps = {
      ref: list => this.list = list,
      onClickOutside: this.handleClickOutside,
      onCancel: this.handleOnEscape,
    }

    if (resultList && resultList.length > 0) {
      return <>{(
--->        <List itemCount={resultList.length} onEnter={this.handleOnEnter} {...listProps}>
            {resultList.map((item, index) => {

              return <>{(
                  <ListItem
                    key={item[this.props.valueField]}
                    onClick={this.handleItemSelection.bind(this, item)}
                  >
                    {item[this.props.displayField]}
                  </ListItem>
              )}
              </>

            })}
          </List>
      )}</>
    }

    return <>{(
      <>
 --->     <List {...listProps}>
          <ListItem className="filterbar-no-data">Veri bulunamadı.</ListItem>
        </List>
      </>

    )}</>
  }

  render() {
    let { value, onChange, onBlur, partofform, valueField, displayField, options, matchPos, ...cleanedProps    } = this.props

    let data

    if (this.textfieldFocused || value === undefined || value === null || !value[displayField]) {
      data = this.state.text
    } else {
      data = value && hasValue(value[displayField]) ? value[displayField] : value
    }

    if (options && this.data !== options) {
      this.data = options
    }

    return <>{(
      <Block className='filterbar-container' onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}>
        <TextField
          name=''
          value={data}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          partofform={false}
          {...cleanedProps}
        />
        <>
          {this.state.open && this.renderResultList(this.state.resultList)}
        </>
      </Block>
    )}</>
  }
```

list.tsx:

```
  render() {
    return <>{(
        <Element
          ref={list => this.list = list}
          tabIndex="0"
          type='ul'
          className='filterbar-list'
          onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
        >
          {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child, index) => {
            return <>{
              (React.cloneElement(child, {
              index: index,
              onFocus: this.handleFocus,
              isFocused: this.state.focusIndex === index,
              isScroll: this.state.isScroll,
            }))}</>
          })}
        </Element>
    )}</>
  }
```

listitem.tsx:

```
  render() {
    let { children, index, className, isFocused } = this.props
    return <>{(
      <Element
        type='li'
        onMouseEnter={this.handleFocus.bind(this, index)}
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
        className={classNames('filterbar-list-item', className, { 'focused': isFocused })}
      >
        {children}
      </Element>
    )}</>
  }
```

I expect this problem would be solved by removing the resolution part of the package.json file.

I tried wrapping the Component with an extra fragment to make sure the Component returned a single JSX component and expected for this issue to be resolved.

I tested by upgrading and downgrading the TypeScript version to make sure the TypeScript version wasn't causing the problem.

What is the issue on this component? How can I solve it? Thank You!

Comment: Why are you returning the JSX elements within a fragment? `<>{( ... )}</>` seems redundant

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, it might be redundant. I only tried to fix error.

Comment: Can you remove the redundant fragments so it can be just: `return (<List>...</List>)`?

Comment: @yadhu I had already added redundant fragments while trying to solve the error. I deleted redundant fragments again, it still gives the same error.

Comment: Understood. Can you also post your package.json? Would like to have a look at the dependencies in particular.